# Hyphen in egrep

Tags: command-line, bash, grep

I run the following command in bash:

```
echo "#fastq-dump SRR3105676 --gzip -O my &" | egrep "-O"
```

and I get

```
grep: invalid option -- 'O'
Usage: grep [OPTION]... PATTERNS [FILE]...
Try 'grep --help' for more information.
```

I understand that to fix this I need to escape the hyphen (dash) in the quotes, but why is this happening? Why is the shell interpreting the "-O" as an option and not as a regex?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The *shell* isn't interpreting anything - it's simply passing `-O` (after quote removal) to the `grep` executable, which parses it as part of its argument vector `argv[]`

You can either signal the end of options using `--`

```
echo "#fastq-dump SRR3105676 --gzip -O my &" | egrep -- "-O"
```

or (for the case of `grep` specifically) use the `-e` option (or its long form `--regexp`) to explicitly tell it that the next argument is an **e**xpression:

```
echo "#fastq-dump SRR3105676 --gzip -O my &" | egrep -e "-O"
```

From `man grep`:

```
   -e PATTERN, --regexp=PATTERN
          Use PATTERN as the pattern.  If this  option  is  used  multiple
          times or is combined with the -f (--file) option, search for all
          patterns given.  This option can be used to  protect  a  pattern
          beginning with “-”.
```